# Discord.py - bot sending information about message instead of message

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord.py

I am trying to make a system where when you react to an emoji, it will send that message (depending on what emoji you reacted with) - to another text-channel, now it is returning this instead of the actual message:

```
<Message id=733788372891467838 channel=<TextChannel id=733721953134837861 name='admin-bug' position=1 nsfw=False news=False category_id=733717942604398684> type=<MessageType.default: 0> author=<Member id=733720584831369236 name='ReefCraft' discriminator='3102' bot=True nick=None guild=<Guild id=733717942604398682 name="Pumbalo's server" shard_id=None chunked=True member_count=2>> flags=<MessageFlags value=0>>
```

I have tried making to use `.content` on the variable, but it still does not work, and it gives me errors:
`discord.errors.HTTPException: 400 Bad Request (error code: 50006): Cannot send an empty message`

Here is my code:

`````
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
import asyncio

TOKEN = '---'
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='!!')

emojis = ["\u2705", "\U0001F6AB", "\u274C"]


@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print('Bot is ready.')


@bot.command()
async def bug(ctx, desc=None, rep=None):
    user = ctx.author
    await ctx.author.send('```Please explain the bug```')
    responseDesc = await bot.wait_for('message', check=lambda message: message.author == ctx.author, timeout=300)
    description = responseDesc.content
    await ctx.author.send('````Please provide pictures/videos of this bug```')
    responseRep = await bot.wait_for('message', check=lambda message: message.author == ctx.author, timeout=300)
    replicate = responseRep.content
    embed = discord.Embed(title='Bug Report', color=0x00ff00)
    embed.add_field(name='Description', value=description, inline=False)
    embed.add_field(name='Replicate', value=replicate, inline=True)
    embed.add_field(name='Reported By', value=user, inline=True)
    adminBug = bot.get_channel(733721953134837861)
    message = await adminBug.send(embed=embed)
    # Add 3 reaction (different emojis) here
    for emoji in emojis:
        await message.add_reaction(emoji)


@bot.event
async def on_reaction_add(reaction, user):
    message = reaction.message
    msg = message.content
    emoji = reaction.emoji

    if user.bot:
        return

    if emoji == "\u2705":
        fixed = bot.get_channel(733722567449509958)
        await fixed.send(msg)

    elif emoji == "\U0001F6AB":
        notBug = bot.get_channel(733722584801083502)
        await notBug.send(message)

    elif emoji == "\u274C":
        notFixed = bot.get_channel(733722600706146324)
        await notFixed.send(message)

    else:
        return

bot.run(TOKEN)
`````

Comment: If your message is an embed, you might have to await `ctx.send(msg.embed)`

Comment: Alright, I'll give it a try whenever discord servers are fixed, thanks!

Comment: did not work @mr_spaar , says that it has no attribute 'embed'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use [`on_raw_reaction_add()`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=on_raw#discord.on_raw_reaction_add), which returns a [`RawReactionActionEvent`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=on_raw#discord.RawReactionActionEvent) object. You'll be able to get the `message_id` and to use [`fetch_message`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=fetch_message#discord.abc.Messageable.fetch_message) to finally get the embed:

```py
@bot.event
async def on_raw_reaction_add(payload):
    channel = bot.get_channel(payload.channel_id)
    msg = await channel.fetch_message(payload.message_id)
    embed = msg.embeds[0]
    emoji = payload.emoji

    if user.bot:
        return

    if emoji == "emoji 1":
        fixed = bot.get_channel(733722567449509958)
        await fixed.send(embed=embed)

    elif emoji == "emoji 2":
        notBug = bot.get_channel(733722584801083502)
        await notBug.send(embed=embed)

    elif emoji == "emoji 3":
        notFixed = bot.get_channel(733722600706146324)
        await notFixed.send(embed=embed)

    else:
        return
```

NB: `payload.emoji` returns a [`discord.PartialEmoji`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=on_raw#discord.PartialEmoji), comparing it to raw unicode might not work anymore.

Comment: Ah, okay. So instead of using the raw unicode, I have to use the 'emoji' variable? Because nothing happens now when I click the reaction. So what should I replace the unicode emoji with?

Comment: Yup, you can click on `discord.PartialEmoji` to see what attributes it has.