# Discord.py - Send embed messages to another channel using reactions

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord.py

So I am trying to make embed messages be transferred between different text channels, there are three options. 'Fixed' - 'Not-A-Bug' - 'Not Fixed'. The admin of the discord server will choose one of these three depending on the situation of a bug.

The issue is that when I react to one of these emotes, it sends information about the message, like this:
`<Message id=735831838555242557 channel=<TextChannel id=733721953134837861 name='admin-bug' position=4 nsfw=False news=False category_id=733717942604398684> type=<MessageType.default: 0> author=<Member id=733720584831369236 name='ReefCraft' discriminator='3102' bot=True nick=None guild=<Guild id=733717942604398682 name="Pumbalo's server" shard_id=None chunked=True member_count=2>> flags=<MessageFlags value=0>>`

I need it to send the embed, so instead of that^^ it should be like this:

[image]

Here is my python code:

````
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
import asyncio

TOKEN = '---'
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='!!')

emojis = ["\u2705", "\U0001F6AB", "\u274C"]

emojis2 = ["\u2705", "\u274C"]


@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print('Bot is ready.')


@bot.command()
async def bug(ctx, desc=None, rep=None):
    user = ctx.author
    await ctx.author.send('```Please explain the bug```')
    responseDesc = await bot.wait_for('message', check=lambda message: message.author == ctx.author, timeout=300)
    description = responseDesc.content
    await ctx.author.send('```Please provide pictures/videos of this bug```')
    responseRep = await bot.wait_for('message', check=lambda message: message.author == ctx.author, timeout=300)
    replicate = responseRep.content
    embed = discord.Embed(title='Bug Report', color=0x00ff00)
    embed.add_field(name='Description', value=description, inline=False)
    embed.add_field(name='Replicate', value=replicate, inline=True)
    embed.add_field(name='Reported By', value=user, inline=True)
    adminBug = bot.get_channel(733721953134837861)
    message = await adminBug.send(embed=embed)
    # Add 3 reaction (different emojis) here
    for emoji in emojis:
        await message.add_reaction(emoji)

@bot.event
async def on_reaction_add(reaction, user):
    message = reaction.message
    emoji = reaction.emoji

    if user.bot:
        return

    if emoji == "\u2705":
        fixed_channel = bot.get_channel(733722567449509958)
        await fixed_channel.send(message)
    elif emoji == "\U0001F6AB":
        notBug = bot.get_channel(733722584801083502)
        await notBug.send(message)
    elif emoji == "\u274C":
        notFixed = bot.get_channel(733722600706146324)
        await notFixed.send(message)
    else:
        return

bot.run(TOKEN)
````

I have gotten some help before, but I never got it to work.

Comment: For a starter you have just exposed your token. Make sure to regen a new one instantly.

Comment: I thought that [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62961876/discord-py-bot-sending-information-about-message-instead-of-message/62965974#62965974) from your last question solved your problem?

Comment: It did work at first, but added a few more things and couldn't get it to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is because you are sending the message object, and not its content.

What you want to be using is `discord.Message.embeds` to get the embed from the message.

You can do this using the principles below:

```
# your reaction message
reaction_message = reaction.message

#fetch the message
message = await reaction_message.channel.fetch_message(reaction_message.id)

# message.embeds is a list of embeds. Here we get get the first embed which is what you need
my_embed = message.embeds[0]

# now send the embed to the channel
await fixed_channel.send(embed=my_embed)
```

Comment: This will cause an error `message has no attribute embeds` if I remember correctly. The message you get from `reaction.message` don't include embeds.

Comment: @Mr_Spaar Ah yes ive updated it to fetch the message now

Comment: The first solution seemed to work fine, so does the second one. Thank you! :)